# How to optimize an hybrid Mobile App for slow internet connections

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an ionic mobile application that has been developed, but it throws a lot of connection error when used on phones with poor internet connection.

Is there a way I can optimize my application to function well on devices with poor internet connection. i.e (GPRS or EDGE connection)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your http calls to contain a longer timeout (here 3 minutes in ms). Also make sure you handle the error case gracefully.

```js
this.http.get(url)
    .timeout(180000)
    .map(...)
    .subcribe(
        (success) => {...},
        (err) => { // Deal here with timeout error.
    }
);
```

Also make sure you cache any data that can be reused using [`ionic-storage`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage), like fonts, images, JSON responses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Network plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

You can check the network change event:

```
// watch network for a disconnect
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
   console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
});
```

And the connection type:

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Maybe you should manage your requests depending on if user has connection and user connection type.